# Creating a true or false column based on another column's values

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_summary_sklearn = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Method','Prediction' , 'is_best'])
df_summary_sklearn['Method'] = ['1-KNN', '5-KNN', '10-KNN']
df_summary_sklearn['Prediction'] = [1, 2, 3] # example data
df_summary_sklearn['is_best'] = np.where((df_summary_sklearn['Prediction']).min(), True, False)

print(df_summary_sklearn)
```

I want to return `True` in the `is_best` column for the minimum value of the `Prediction` column, and `False` for the rest. So what I want is this:

```
   Method  Prediction  is_best
0   1-KNN           1     True
1   5-KNN           2    False
2  10-KNN           3    False
```

But what I'm currently getting is this:

```
   Method  Prediction  is_best
0   1-KNN           1     True
1   5-KNN           2     True
2  10-KNN           3     True
```

How do I correctly create this column?

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have a minimum working example, I've taken contrived values for the `Prediction` column.

```
df_summary_sklearn = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Method','Prediction' , 'is_best'])
df_summary_sklearn['Method'] = ['1-KNN', '5-KNN', '10-KNN']
df_summary_sklearn['Prediction'] = [1, 2, 3]

# This returns a boolean array where the condition holds True.
df_summary_sklearn['Prediction'] == df_summary_sklearn['Prediction'].min()

# Set the is_best column to the result of the previous statement.
df_summary_sklearn['is_best'] = df_summary_sklearn['Prediction'] == df_summary_sklearn['Prediction'].min()
```

This gives the following output.

```
>>> df_summary_sklearn
   Method  Prediction  is_best
0   1-KNN           1     True
1   5-KNN           2    False
2  10-KNN           3    False
```

You can replace the `[1, 2, 3]` in the above example by your own values, say `[one_fold, five_fold, ten_fold]` in your question.